# How to skip silent login?

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm trying to retrieve info from a web page that is protected by username and password.

I went through authentication, sending POST with my username and password. After that I get back response object with redirecting page. When I browse that page I see that I must wait a few seconds or click continue to get to main page. My problem is how to skip this redirection or force the script to go to the main page.

```
import requests

main_url = 'https://my_main_page.com/edit#'
login = {
    'USER' : 'username',
    'PASSWORD' : 'password',    
}     
r = requests.post(main_url,
                  data=login,) #here I have now redirecting page with the
                               #url as main_url , but in page source I see
                               #redirecting page, not my expected page 
print r.url
print r.text
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`r = requests.post(main_url, data=login, allow_redirects=false)`

Comment: It doesn't work :/, my script doesn't response if I set allow_redirect=False . In my web browser if I log in I get a message that informs me after few second I will be redirected to main page. It takes maybe one second and I am on the main page. How do this in script ? :/

Comment: You want to go to the main page or not? If you want it, try allow_redirects=True. Tell me if it works please

Comment: it also doesn't work . I think I need to create session but, I don't know exactly how .

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help you:
http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#redirection-and-history

Maybe you need to use the request method instead. But the post method should work also with the request arguments:
http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/#requests.request

Comment: It doesn't work :( even if I try to use requests.request with my data it still take me to silent login and I am on redirecting page and can't go back to main page.

Comment: Ok you can't go back, but you could also start a new request after you logged in. Something like `r = request.get(main_url)`

Comment: Yes, but in this case it still get me to silent login page .

Comment: Maybe you don't have opened a session. When you login to a page a session is opened by the server. That normaly is stored inside a cookie (sometimes inside the url with get). When you make your second request maybe the server opens a new session. Try to use the session object: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/

Comment: So, how can I do this ? I should create session and then after get/post retrieve cookies from ResponseObject ? I don't understand this. Can you help me on some example ?

Comment: It is not so easy to give you a scipt example over the comments. But there are 2 elements in logging in somewhere. There is ther server and the client. So is that site your website? Is your url that one, which is expecting post requests for login? Maybe the login is done over ajax and is not part of the /edit/ page so you are sending posts request to the wrong page.